# How to implement an (iOS) action sheet but with multiple buttons in one line?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, action

I am wondering that how to implement the action sheet like the iPhone built-in photo edit app.

Go to the Photos app, then select one photo, then click crop button. There is a button called Constrain. Clicking that, an action sheet ( or a popover view?) Will show up. It has 3 buttons on one line. But seems action sheet can only have one button in a line.

So how do I do that?

Comment: Private subclass. Don't even dream about it.

Answer (score 3):

Write your own view and viewController. Design the view to look as you want, when you want to show the 'action sheet' have your controller animate the view in from the bottom just as the system does. Its not all that hard to do a custom sheet like this. Do yourself a favor, don't add the code to your existing VC, but create a new class with a delegate and a simple protocol, so that it acts a bit like the action sheet. when the user finally taps the button the protocol returns the result using a protocol callback. You can then reuse this class elsewhere (or post it on github for fame and fortune!)

Comment: David, finally I followed your advice and have some code to get the action sheet I wanted. The code is here: https://github.com/russj/MBActionSheet

Comment: Great! Glad this worked out for you. Will look at your code soon. You could accept my answer as the solution, we both get points if you do so.